# How to extend the Orchard CMS to support the features of a custom portal?

Tags: orchardcms

I am kind of new to Orchard CMS and I need to implement some kind of a portal on this technology. Basically the system need to have a couple of blogs and some additional content types (like events, webcasts, photo galleries etc). Whenever I navigate to a blog (for example http://localhost/OrchardLocal/blog1/) I want to have a menu with the following actions:

- Latests posts - which will contain the latests posts of that blog
- Webcasts - which will display the entries of type Webcast from the owner of the blog
- Photo Galleries - same as Webcasts but with Photo Galleries
- Events - same as Webcasts but with Events

On the main page of the portal (http://localhost/OrchardLocal/) I need to somehow have all this information aggregated. So I have to be able to see the latest posts, webcasts, photo galleries and events from all the authors.

I would like to know what would be the best approach to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great blog post abount [finding content in Orchard](http://www.deepcode.co.uk/2011/06/real-world-orchard-cmspart-7finding.html) which should give you enough to start with.

If you want to implement the links as a menu you might want to look at the `INavigationProvider` interface which has a couple of good implementations (notably [Pszmyd's Advanced Menu Module](http://www.orchardproject.net/gallery/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu) as well as the core Orchard ones).